# Function from class works when called directly, but returns error when called from a different class with an instance of original

Tags: python

I wrote a little code for a class called Game, which uses another class called Board.

One of the functions in `Board` is `check_horizontal_win(self, row, original_col)`.

When I use it directly on a Board object it works fine. When I try to use it with the Game's board (`Game.get_board().check_horizontal_win)`) I get:

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'check_horizontal_win'
```

I've checked and I don't seem to be using anything private or illegal.  And the values in the two cases were the same.

Here's the first class, Game.  The last line of code in the "main" doesn't work:

```
from board import *

PLAYER_A = 1
PLAYER_B = 2
INITIAL_ROW = 0
INITIAL_COLUMN = 0
FINAL_ROW = 5
FINAL_COLUMN = 6
ILLEGAL_LOCATION_MSG = "Illegal location."
ILLEGAL_MOVE_MSG = "Illegal move."
IS_GAME_WON = False
WINNER = None

class Game:

    def __init__(self):
        self.__current_player = PLAYER_A
        self.__board = Board()

    def make_move(self, column):
        """  Makes move and updates board and current player, if column is a valid choice and game is ongoing.  """
        if self.__board.is_col_illegal(column):
            raise Exception(ILLEGAL_MOVE_MSG)
        self.do_move(column)

    def do_move(self, column):
        """  Actual implementation of the move.  """
        if self.__current_player == PLAYER_A:
            self.__board.update_board(column, PLAYER_A)
            self.__current_player = PLAYER_B
        elif self.__current_player == PLAYER_B:
            self.__board.update_board(column, PLAYER_B)
            self.__current_player = PLAYER_A

    def get_winner(self):
       pass

    def get_player_at(self, row, col):
        """  Returns the player whose disc is at the given position in the game.  """
        if row < INITIAL_ROW or row > FINAL_ROW or col < INITIAL_COLUMN or col > FINAL_COLUMN:
            raise Exception(ILLEGAL_LOCATION_MSG)

        return self.__board.get_board()[row][col]

    def get_current_player(self):
        """  Returns current_player.  """
        return self.__current_player

    def get_board(self):
        """  Returns board."""
        return self.__board

if __name__ == '__main__':

    game = Game()
    game.make_move(0)
    game.make_move(1)
    game.make_move(0)
    game.make_move(2)
    game.get_board.check_horizontal_win(0, 1)
```

And here's the Board class.  In this case, the function in the main does work:

```
NUM_ROWS = 6
NUM_COLUMNS = 7
INITIAL_VALUE = None
WIN_COUNT = 4


class Board:

    def __init__(self):
        self.__playboard = []
        self.__available_rows_list = NUM_COLUMNS*[NUM_ROWS-1]
        initial_row = NUM_COLUMNS * [INITIAL_VALUE]
        for i in range(NUM_ROWS):
            self.__playboard.append(initial_row.copy())

    def get_playboard(self):
        """  Returns board.  """
        return self.__playboard

    def update_board(self, col, val):
        """  Updates current status of board.  """
        row = self.__available_rows_list[col]
        self.__playboard[row][col] = val
        self.__update_row(col)

    def __update_row(self, col):
        """  Updates available_row_list.  """
        if self.__available_rows_list[col] > 0:
            self.__available_rows_list[col] = self.__available_rows_list[col] - 1
        else:
            self.__available_rows_list[col] = None

    def __is_col_available(self, col):
        """  Checks if given col has empty spaces left on the playboard.  """
        if self.__available_rows_list[col] == None:
            return False
        return True

    def __is_col_exist(self, col):
        """  Checks if given column is within the capacity of the playboard.  """
        if col < 0 or col >= NUM_COLUMNS:
            return False
        return True

    def is_col_illegal(self, col):
        """  Checks if given column is an illegal option.  """
        if not self.__is_col_available(col) or not self.__is_col_exist(col):
            return True
        return False

    def print_playboard(self):
        for row in self.__playboard:
            print(row)

    def check_horizontal_win(self, row, original_col):
        """  Checks if player has won in the horizontal direction.  """

        # check if row and col were valid?  Or do it somewhere else?
        count = 1
        player = self.__playboard[row][original_col]
        col = original_col
        while self.__is_col_exist(col) and self.__playboard[row][col] == player:
            count = count + 1
            if count == WIN_COUNT:
                return True
            col = col + 1
        # Then: undergo same process, this time in the opposite direction (the left).
        col = original_col - 1
        while self.__is_col_exist(col) and self.__playboard[row][col] == player:
            count = count + 1
            if count == WIN_COUNT:
                return True
            col = col - 1


if __name__ == '__main__':

    board = Board()
    board.update_board(0,1)
    board.update_board(0, 1)
    board.update_board(1, 2)
    board.update_board(2, 2)
    board.print_playboard()
    board.check_horizontal_win(0, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You wrote:

```
game.get_board.check_horizontal_win(0, 1)
```

Make that:

```
game.get_board().check_horizontal_win(0, 1)
```